# MSVC 2017 not compiling for 64-bit even when x64 target is selected

Tags: visual-studio

I'm kind of new to using Microsoft Visual Studio on Windows as much of my programming experience is with GNU/Linux systems but I'm being required now to use Windows for this project, and I've run into a problem. In particular, I recently downloaded and installed a fresh install of Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (I can't afford the professional version and I don't think I need the extra features beyond the compiler for this), and I wanted to compile a C++ program for 64-bit Windows. But it doesn't seem to work: even if I have the build target (on the top toolbar) set to "x64" instead of "x86", when I build a simple program which puts out "sizeof(long)", it gives "4", not the expected "8", suggesting that even though it is set to x64 mode it is still compiling for 32-bit!

Why is this? I made sure to select when installing the Visual Studio package to install the toolset marked with both "x86,x64" and yet it seems like it is not accessing the x64 compilers! (And yes the Windows version itself is 64-bit.). What is going on? Is more configuration required than just what comes out of the box?